# Compressed air efficiency if expansion cooling is used

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, forces, fluid-dynamics

Compressed air energy storage is looked down upon because of the inefficiencies it brings along. Every article I've found till today, makes use of the stored energy by converting it into mechanical torque of a shaft, and more often than not, converting the mechanical to electrical energy.

Is there a reason why, on a domestic scale, we cannot use the cooling of the air as it expands for air conditioning, along with whatever energy it provides of the mechanical kind? Please provide some sample calculations too if you can.

My own thinking would be to adiabatically pressurize a cylinder buried in a bunch of sand, which would absorb whatever low grade heat is given off, and then to decompress through a turbine to turn a shaft, while the exhaust cool air can be used for air conditioning?

What aspect will be uneconomical or unrealistic? Space required, efficiency, safety standards, what?

Leakages from valves when decompressing are always counted as an inefficiency. If we simply pass the leakages along with exhaust cool air from the components to come (turbine etc.) through a heat exchanger, that can be used for air conditioning! Why is it a loss?

Similarly, heat loss when compressing can be captured by the aforementioned sand (or water etc) which will be preheated for heating applications elsewhere. I understand the compressed air will never give us back that energy when decompressing, but the capturing media will!

Comment: Instead of using power to compress air, you are likely far better off using that power to run a heat pump. Joule-Thompson cooling is not exactly efficient.

Comment: @JonCuster Yes, but can we store energy in a heat pump? I speak of it in terms of energy storage.

Comment: @JonCuster For example, will a thermal energy storage running a steam turbine which powers the heat pump be more efficient than this?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a reason why, on a domestic scale, we cannot use the cooling of the air as it expands for air conditioning, along with whatever energy it provides of the mechanical kind?

Essentially this is exactly what an A/C unit does: It uses a refrigerant, not air, which cools by expansion (actually by throttling that produces evaporative cooling). The A/C consume electricity to re-compress the expanded refrigerant and repeat the cycle.

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to understand the effect it would have on the efficiency of a compressed air energy storage system. Isn't it going to make the recovery from decompression 100% efficient, as the "waste" is the coolness of air, but we make it useful in our setup?